# What is the physical shape of a rapidly spinning singularity?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, singularities, kerr-metric

Let's say I have a star 20x the mass of the sun.  At the end of its life, it collapses into a black hole.  Now correct me if I am wrong, but as it collapses it rotational speed dramatically increases doesn't it?  So does the singularity continue spinning as it forms?  Can something spinning so rapidly actually become a singularity or would it become more of a torus?

Comment: You make an invalid assumption that a collapsing star creates a singularity. It doesn't. The singularity never forms in the eternity of time for any remote observer.

Answer (score 1):

Spinning black holes are governed by the Kerr metric, and have a [ring singularity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_singularity) or "ringularity". A ringularity has a finite radius but no thickness so would not be described as a torus.

Comment: Would most solar black holes be ringularities?

Comment: @rick it is unlikely and perhaps impossible for a real black hole to have exactly zero angular momentum.